# type error after dereferencing pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c++

I'm curious as to why the following code doesn't work. In particular, the compiler seems to be viewing *(result + i) as a gVector3 type as opposed to a float. But result is a pointer to a float array right? So wouldn't dereferencing a pointer return a float? You can assume that gVector3 and gMatrix3 are defined.

```
    /* returns the column vector at index i */
    gVector3 gMatrix3::getColumn(unsigned int index) const{
    gVector3* result = new gVector3();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            *(result + i) = data[i][index];
        }
        return *result;
    }
```

Comment: If it's a pointer to a `float` array, dereferencing it would give a `float` array. As is, it's a pointer to a single *thing* and you're pretending there's a direct array of *things* involved when you do `result + i`.

Comment: If you type int* ptr = new int[3], ptr should store the address of the first element of the array right?

Comment: so in this case, gVector3 is defined as a float array. i kind of see what you're saying, but why would this be different?

Comment: Wait, that code doesn't even compile if it's a float array. Perhaps you meant a pointer.

Comment: sorry, gVector3 is not a float array, it's a class with a float array in its member field

Comment: In that case, the answer looks about right, although I don't see why you wouldn't just do `gVector3 result;` and `result[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

If gVector3 is a class, then it probably overloads `operator[]`, which is what you should use. Otherwise you're performing pointer arithmetic on the object itself. Try this:

```
(*result)[i] = data[i][index];
```

Comment: ok thanks guys, this worked! so (*result) returns the vector class type, allows us to use the overloaded [] operator?